# What is the equivalent of this xaml binding in code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, code-behind

I have a xaml TextBlock bound as follows:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
```

How do I access SelectedItem.LastName in C# codebehind? Thanks.

Details:

Data are from an XML file

```
 <Player>
 <LastName>...</LastName>
 <Age>...</Age>
 </Player>
```

The combobox binding was simplified for clarity as above in the xaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx

```
MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);      
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Answer (score 1):

SelectedItem belongs to `playerComboBox'.  So it should be:

```
(playerComboBox.SelectedItem as TypeOfselectedItem).LastName
```

Comment: Anurag, by TypeOfselectedItem do you mean I need to replace it with other type like String or double depending on the type of LastName ? Because I don't see that keyword. If so, what to do if the type of selected item is anonymous. Thanks.

Comment: Please add code to your question on how and what you are binding to the playerComboBox.  The _TypeOfSelectedItem_ is the object that holds _LastName_.

Comment: I simplified and added some more code. Now I want to access LastName and Age in the code behind when an item in the combobox is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Modified answer above:

```
var selectedPlayer = (Player)playerComboBox.SelectedItem;
var age = selectedPlayer.Age;
var lastName = selectedPlayer.LastName;
```

Seems like this is what you're looking for.

---

**UPDATE**(if *"there is no Player class"*):

```
dynamic player = playerComboBox.SelectedItem;
int age = player.Age;
string lasName = player.LastName;
```

Comment: My problem is that there is no Player class. The type is anonymous. If I do a playerComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() it shows the whole XML node in { ... }.

Comment: When I do a playerComboBox.SelectedItem.GetType().ToString() it says it's an anonymous type: <>f_AnonymousType0`2...

Comment: Please, provide xaml part within which you declare combobox (including binding and templates).